# Avahi-dnsconfd new pre-removal script throws an error when updating

Tags: apt, ubuntu-mate

I am using MATE 16.04 on an ASUS X550LA with 12 GB RAM, single user, FIREFOX 59.0.1 64 bit with DuckDuckGo.

Running Ubuntu Software Updater gave me following:-

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb: subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
```

After running Synaptic Package Manager to update, I also keep getting this message.

There do not appear to any problems with running any applications or in using the internet.

I shut down completely and did a cold reboot, but no change.

Can anyone help me resolve this and explain what the problem is please?

Comment: Command line :-dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Job for avahi-daemon.socket canceled.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Also here during 'apt update'

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 :( EDIT: resolved with my answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768620

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon
```