# Package operation failed

Tags: package-management

When I ran software updater, everything went fine except for Avahi DNS config Tool. It told me:

```
Package operation failed. Installation or removal of package failed.
```

I have tried:

```
apt -y update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get clean
apt -y autoremove
```

Comment: fixit7: Please update your post with details as to version of Ubuntu you are running. This just happened to me too on my Ubuntu system: https://i.imgur.com/CGvrqdF.png running Ubuntu 17.10 (so is in need of an upgrade anyhow).  And by the way, a huge defect here is that there is no way for the user to see the specific error from that popup window, thus forcing you to play games with apt-get etc.

Comment: Run "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" to see more specific error messages regarding the update process, and post these here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: It's been a long time since I posted the question. The problem is resolved but I can not remember what I did. Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

First command is worth to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then step by step:

```
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but am the bounty hunter (giver???). See gist at https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/8ba499bb9debdbb75c9b2e3e5e87e828 for my execution of those commands, with two additional commands listed at the end. For me I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 as I indicated in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027919/package-operation-failed/1054931#comment1724933_1027919 so I have not proceeded to do any repair yet, just listing what I have so far.

Comment: I next tried `sudo apt upgrade` and it also failed but generated more detailed error messages (ignore the curses codes as I'm using a dumb terminal to run these commands): https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/f0119a584f659c668551b4ebf93af890

Comment: Tried `sudo apt autoremove` as was indicated in https://askubuntu.com/a/1054931/340383 : https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/d43d7321b3fdf0edf23c507339219265  (of course I do not expect this to fix anything, done just for completeness)

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the error message that I kept encountering at https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/d77d997fe02af47c3a837e9b94256897#file-transcript_log6-txt-L26 which was:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
```

and found the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1022548/340383 that has the final commands I used that fixed the problem.

[Package operation failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027919/package-operation-failed#comment1729394_1054931) is the result.

Now running Software Updater finishes successfully and is requiring a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

A few other things to try:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

That normally fixes partial or broken installations. If it fails, add the output messages to your original question.

Comment: I tried that and got no error messages, but got no obvious messaging that indicated that it actually did anything: https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/e9cbbc57778c6310fbcd2fae30757145  (and this was after running `sudo apt autoremove` at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027919/package-operation-failed#comment1729015_1054924 in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

This probably mean something was stuck in "dependency hell" or dpkg just messed up somewhere. To fix this try these commands.

Try forcefully deleting and refreshing your package lists with new remote ones.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt update
```

Once done, try cleaning and removing unnecessary files & packages.

```
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
```

Remove the package you are having trouble with.

```
sudo apt remove <package>
```

Next, try getting dpkg to resolve the issue on it's own.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Next, try getting apt to resolve the issue on it's own.

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Last, try installing it again.

```
sudo apt install <package>
```

You could help all of us by running "lsb_release" and telling us which version of Ubuntu you are running, and also provide the contents of your /etc/apt.d/sources.list.

Comment: Earlier at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027919/package-operation-failed#comment1729347_1054918 I had done all steps up to, but not including, the `sudo apt remove <package>` step. So I did that step now, and got an error. See gist: https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/11258fdc2cde3961f75f0263383926b3

Comment: I continued on with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and got similar errors: https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/d77d997fe02af47c3a837e9b94256897

Comment: I see https://askubuntu.com/a/1022548/340383 has some commands. Trying them seemed to fix the issue: https://gist.github.com/bgoodr/b134bac04fcc2243005b4ed88dabb208